# Оушен Драйв, Оушен-Драйв чи Оушен-драйв?

Tags: правопис, власні-назви, іншомовні-слова

У місті Маямі-Біч, штат Флорида, є набережна вулиця під назвою Ocean Drive. Як правильно її писати українською, Оушен Драйв, Оушен-Драйв чи Оушен-драйв?

Українська Вікіпедія [подає](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BC%D1%96-%D0%91%D1%96%D1%87#%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0) Оушен Драйв без дефісу, обидва слова з великої, однак український правопис [вказує](https://2019.pravopys.net/sections/50/) назви вулиць на зразок Мічиган-авеню через дефіс, друге слово з малої за правилом:

`з малої букви пишемо й родові позначення в іншомовних назвах вулиць, майданів, бульварів`

Answer (score 4):

- У ГРАК-9 частіше «Ххх-драйв», ніж «Ххх Драйв»:

  - [`[`

        `word="[А-Я].*" &`

        `lc=".*-драйв(а|у|ові|ом|і|и|ів|ам|ами|ах)?" &`

        `lc!="(авто|кіно|муз|тест)-.*"`

    `]`](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac9&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%5Bword=%22%5B%D0%90-%D0%AF%5D.*%22+%26+lc=%22.*-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2(%D0%B0%7C%D1%83%7C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%7C%D0%BE%D0%BC%7C%D1%96%7C%D0%B8%7C%D1%96%D0%B2%7C%D0%B0%D0%BC%7C%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%7C%D0%B0%D1%85)?%22+%26+lc!=%22(%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%7C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%7C%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B7%7C%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82)-.*%22%5D) — 102 результати;
  - [`(`

        `[word="[А-Я].*" & tag!=".*(abbr|adj|adv|conj|noun|prep|verb).*"]`

        `[lc="драйв(а|у|ові|ом|і|и|ів|ам|ами|ах)?"]`

    `) | (`

        `[word="[А-Я].*" & tag!=".*(abbr|adj|adv|conj|prep|verb).*"]`

        `[lc="драйв(а|ові|ом|і|и|ів|ам|ами|ах)?"]`

    `)`](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac9&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=(%5Bword=%22%5B%D0%90-%D0%AF%5D.*%22+%26+tag!=%22.*(abbr%7Cadj%7Cadv%7Cconj%7Cnoun%7Cprep%7Cverb).*%22%5D+%5Blc=%22%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2(%D0%B0%7C%D1%83%7C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%7C%D0%BE%D0%BC%7C%D1%96%7C%D0%B8%7C%D1%96%D0%B2%7C%D0%B0%D0%BC%7C%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%7C%D0%B0%D1%85)?%22%5D)+%7C+(%5Bword=%22%5B%D0%90-%D0%AF%5D.*%22+%26+tag!=%22.*(abbr%7Cadj%7Cadv%7Cconj%7Cprep%7Cverb).*%22%5D+%5Blc=%22%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2(%D0%B0%7C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%7C%D0%BE%D0%BC%7C%D1%96%7C%D0%B8%7C%D1%96%D0%B2%7C%D0%B0%D0%BC%7C%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%7C%D0%B0%D1%85)?%22%5D)) — 60 результатів (перелік [виключених результатів](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac9&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=(%5Bword=%22%5B%D0%90-%D0%AF%5D.*%22+%26+tag=%22.*(abbr%7Cadj%7Cadv%7Cconj%7Cprep%7Cverb).*%22%5D+%5Blc=%22%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2(%D0%B0%7C%D1%83%7C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%7C%D0%BE%D0%BC%7C%D1%96%7C%D0%B8%7C%D1%96%D0%B2%7C%D0%B0%D0%BC%7C%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%7C%D0%B0%D1%85)?%22%5D)+%7C+(%5Bword=%22%5B%D0%90-%D0%AF%5D.*%22+%26+tag=%22.*noun.*%22%5D+%5Blc=%22%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D1%83%22%5D))).
- Правопис-2019 теж начебто натякає, що має бути «Ххх-драйв» (хоча й не зазначає явно «-драйв» у переліку родових назв).

Тому, мабуть, «**Оушен-драйв**».